# Momentjs diff and then humanize returning same output for opposite values

Tags: momentjs

**Description of the Issue and Steps to Reproduce:**

I am using latest (2.19.1) version of moment library. I am having an input date (let's say 5:00 pm today) and then subtracting it from current time and then humanize it.

```
moment.duration(moment({hour:17}).diff(moment({hour:16, minute:45}))).humanize()   //output: 15 minutes
moment.duration(moment({hour:17}).diff(moment({hour:17, minute:15}))).humanize()   //output: 15 minutes
```

For line 2 above, it should differentiate output from line 1, which is just opposite.

Based on outcome of humanize, I'm displaying message on UI, like '15 minutes remaining'. But because of same output for opposite values I'm unable to display proper message.

Although I have raised this issue with Momentjs team at [github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4285) as well but wondering if someone can help here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`humanize(true)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/)

> By default, the return string is suffixless. If you want a suffix, pass in true as seen below.

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment.duration(moment({hour:17}).diff(moment({hour:16, minute:45}))).humanize(true) );   //output: in 15 minutes
console.log( moment.duration(moment({hour:17}).diff(moment({hour:17, minute:15}))).humanize(true) );   //output: 15 minutes ago
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you need, you can customize how moment displays [Relative Time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) using `updateLocale`.

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s remaining"
    }
});

console.log( moment.duration(moment({hour:17}).diff(moment({hour:16, minute:45}))).humanize(true) );   //output: in 15 minutes
console.log( moment.duration(moment({hour:17}).diff(moment({hour:17, minute:15}))).humanize(true) );   //output: 15 minutes ago
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```